# Webpack chunk load at run time

Tags: django, webpack

I'm writing a template for this Django app, inside it I load a .js file built with webpack:

```
<script src="{{ ROOT }}/material/build/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is found, I can also access it in the browser it's under:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app_static/personalization/js/app/material/build/
```

The problem is the webpack config also creates a chunk `0.0.js` which cannot be found, from what I understand app.js uses it somehow but it's not searching for it in the same folder it resides, instead it searches for it at the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/personalization/material/958cb30c8751ff63160d7b22a69a9ec6/build/0.0.js
```

This url is defined in my urls.py, it's the url I'm at before trying to do a `render_to_response("api/js_app_material.html", context_data, c)` which causes the `0.0.js` file to not be found.

My question is: can I somehow configure webpack to let it know to search for the chunks in the folder where app.js resides? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into something similar and this was the issue for me:

if you are using

```
 require(['app.jsx'], function (app) {
 });
```

try to change it with

```
var app = require('app.jsx');
```